# magento frondend and backend show error

Tags: php, magento, content-management-system, magento-1.9

My magento frontend and backend not load and show error.

How I can fix this?

Notice: error show after I disable all modules (I know that's wrong).

How I can fix this?

I'm Beginner in magento.

Thank you for help.

```
Notice: Undefined index: httponly  in   
D:\xampp\htdocs\magento\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Session\Abstract\Varien.php on line 104

#0 D:\xampp\htdocs\magento\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Session\Abstract\Varien.php(104): mageCoreErrorHandler(8, 'Undefined index...', 'D:\\xampp\\htdocs...', 104, Array)
#1 D:\xampp\htdocs\magento\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Session\Abstract\Varien.php(222): Mage_Core_Model_Session_Abstract_Varien->start('frontend')
#2 D:\xampp\htdocs\magento\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Session\Abstract.php(84): Mage_Core_Model_Session_Abstract_Varien->init('core', 'frontend')
#3 D:\xampp\htdocs\magento\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Session.php(42): Mage_Core_Model_Session_Abstract->init('core', 'frontend')
#4 D:\xampp\htdocs\magento\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Config.php(1348): Mage_Core_Model_Session->__construct(Array)
#5 D:\xampp\htdocs\magento\magento\app\Mage.php(463): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getModelInstance('core/session', Array)
#6 D:\xampp\htdocs\magento\magento\app\Mage.php(477): Mage::getModel('core/session', Array)
#7 D:\xampp\htdocs\magento\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(493): Mage::getSingleton('core/session', Array)
#8 D:\xampp\htdocs\magento\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Front\Action.php(64): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->preDispatch()
#9 D:\xampp\htdocs\magento\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(407): Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action->preDispatch()
#10 D:\xampp\htdocs\magento\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Router\Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#11 D:\xampp\htdocs\magento\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#12 D:\xampp\htdocs\magento\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#13 D:\xampp\htdocs\magento\magento\app\Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#14 D:\xampp\htdocs\magento\magento\index.php(89): Mage::run('', 'store')
#15 {main}
```

Comment: I think you may want to add the relevant code.

Comment: what code from what page in magento?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to disable module which only reside in local or community. except Cm_reddis and Phoenix extension. then refresh cache  and check it.

Comment: Thanks colleague,please  more describing about what should i do in Magento, becuase i am beginner in this case